# Is there a way to select cells in an Excel row to auto-populate into cells in a separate Workbook each time a new row is added?

Tags: excel, power-automate, ms-forms

I need to send RFQs to various vendors using their specific forms which are Excel formatted. I need specific information from my co-workers in order to properly fill out the vendor's forms. I was thinking about using MS Forms to gather the specific info I need from my co-workers, then hoping some how that data could easily/automatically be transferred to the vendor's specific Excel form based on the MS Forms responses. The responses received determine which vendor form, and in most cases multiple vendor forms, to use. Then each completed form saved as its own file.

I was looking at different MS Flows, PowerApps, and Power Automate templates that have already been created, but I'm sure one matches my needs or if any of those are the best solution. I did watch some videos about how to create your own MS Flow/PowerApp, but I wasn't sure it was going to be a viable solution. I am hoping to streamline the action of copying & pasting the data, but I'm not sure how I would go about setting up a way, if there is one. Or if there is a "dummies" how to way or if the way would be over my head.

Background knowledge/experience: I have zero experience or base knowledge of coding. I can record macros, but cannot edit the coding, I have to re-record it from scratch. I can do simple IF formula's & Pivot Tables in Excel. I tried for a minute to teach myself PowerBi, but think knowing SQL first would be better from my understanding. Haven't dived down rabbit hole of trying to teach myself SQL, if that's even possible without some base coding knowledge. I want to learn these things and how to do more, but lack of time is a factor. I piece and squeeze in micromillimeters of knowledge in when I can from Googling and YouTube. I haven't had much luck Googling this, because what I'm typing in the search bar isn't producing helpful results as far as I can tell.

Comment: You Would create a flow Triggered flow in Power Automate based on the submission of the Form. Get the outputs of the form, create an IF statement in Power Automate, then use Office Scripts to fill out the companies Excel forms

Comment: https://youtu.be/LHDfyxf9BNc here is a great example of how